# Git not responding, how to recover?

Tags: git, recovery

I recently started working with Git. Now my repository seems to be broken and I don't know how to restore it.

Several commands like:

```
git status 
git checkout 'branchname'
git commit
```

don't respond anymore. I can still checkout with `-f` but on each branch it is the same.

Running

```
git fsck
```

gives me several dangling blobs and one dangling commit. I have no idea how to start.

Comment: What doesn't work about?  Do you get error messages that you can share with us?

Comment: I edited my post. The problem is that the commands don't respond. The terminal doesn't respond so I ultimately interrupt it via ^C.

Comment: If you create a new repo and test commit a few files.  Does it work then?

Comment: Yes it does. I also have a different repository which still works perfectly fine.

Comment: Have you added any hooks, configs or changed anything in the .git directory?

Comment: I don't really now about hooks yet, so I shouldn't have added any. The gitconfig is still my basic one. I didn't change anything in the .git directory.

Comment: My last action probably were a git reset, then deleting some folders and trying to checkout another branch. Sadly this isn't in my bash history anymore so I am not sure. The checkout didn't work as I had not commited changes. But from then on I couldn't commit anymore.

Comment: Which OS are you using?  Also, do you have a remote you can recover from?

Comment: I am using Debian 8.6. I still have a little outdated remote. But I am also interested how my mistake could occur to avoid it.

Comment: Is there any output if you try `git log`?

Comment: If you move the current `.git` directory, then `git init` in your working directory, do the commands work?

Comment: `git log` still shows me the history of the successful previous commits. If I move the `.git` git directory to another directory, i can `init` a new repository, but my local branches are lost. `git init` in presence of the `.git` directory can be used to reinitialize the existing repository, but that doesn't fix anything.

Comment: The commands you've described do nothing more then file IO. Check that there are no drive errors or bad sectors. Make sure that the files in the repo are not on a network based file system. And make sure that the files you are committing to git are sane files. (If you are moving branches with files that are HUGE then the process could take a long time and look frozen.)